# Working On A Favorite Websites App

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

**Edit:** I've made some updates to this ever since I got responses to this thread. Here's the new thread:

I've been making an Android application where you would save your favorite websites. Here is what I got for the code in the file 'MainActivity.java' so far:

```js
package cory.assignment.favoritewebsitesapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
 
 private static final String SEARCHES = "searches";
 
 private EditText queryEditText;
 private EditText tagEditText;
 private SharedPreferences savedSearches;
 private ArrayList<String> tags;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  queryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.queryEditText);
  tagEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tagEditText);
  
  savedSearches = getSharedPreferences(SEARCHES, MODE_PRIVATE);
  
  tags = new ArrayList<String>(savedSearches.getAll().keySet());
  Collections.sort(tags, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, tags);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
  
  ImageButton saveButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
  saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
  
  getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
  
  getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(itemLongClickListener);
 }
 
 public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
 {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
   if (queryEditText.getText().length() > 0 && tagEditText.getText().length() > 0)
   {
    addTaggedSearch(queryEditText.getText().toString(), tagEditText.getText().toString());
    queryEditText.setText("");
    tagEditText.setText("");
   
    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(tagEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
   else
   {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
   
    builder.setMessage(R.string.missingMessage);
    
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, null);
   
    AlertDialog errorDialog = builder.create();
    errorDialog.show();
   }
  }
 };
 private void addTaggedSearch(String query, String tag)
 {
  SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
  preferencesEditor.putString(tag, query);
  preferencesEditor.apply();
  
  if (!tags.contains(tags))
  {
   tags.add(tag);
   Collections.sort(tags, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
 }
 OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener()
 {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
   String tag = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
   String urlString = getString(R.string.searchURL) + Uri.encode(savedSearches.getString(tag, ""), "UTF-8");
   
   Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString));
   
   startActivity(webIntent);
  }
 };
 OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener =
  new OnItemLongClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
     final String tag = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
     
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
     
     builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.shareEditDeleteTitle, tag));
     
     builder.setItems(R.array.dialog_items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
       switch (which)
       {
        case 0:
         shareSearch(tag);
         break;
        case 1:
         tagEditText.setText(tag);
         queryEditText.setText(savedSearches.getString(tag, ""));
         break;
        case 2:
         deleteSearch(tag);
         break;
       }
      }
     }
    );
     
    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
      {
       dialog.cancel();
      }
     }
    );
    
    builder.create().show();
    return true;
   }
  };
  private void shareSearch(String tag)
  {
   String urlString = getString(R.string.searchURL) + Uri.encode(savedSearches.getString(tag, ""), "UTF-8");
   
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
   shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.shareSubject));
   shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.shareMessage, urlString));
   shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
   
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.shareSearch)));
  }
  private void deleteSearch(final String tag)
  {
   AlertDialog.Builder confirmBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   
   confirmBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.confirmMessage, tag));
   
   confirmBuilder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
      {
       dialog.cancel();
      }
     }
    );
   
   confirmBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.delete), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
     {
      tags.remove(tag);
      
      SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
      preferencesEditor.remove(tag);
      preferencesEditor.apply();
      
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
    }
   );
  confirmBuilder.create().show();
  }
 }
```

However, I have got the errors for the code with certain lines:

**Line 79:** OK cannot be resolved or is not a field

**Line 146:** cancel cannot be resolved or is not a field

**Line 177:** cancel cannot be resolved or is not a field

**Line 186:** delete cannot be resolved or is not a field

The link below shows what I have for activity_main.xml:
[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLwXR.png)

What could be wrong with those lines? Something isn't right with those lines as they are related to the info on [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html).

I am also using the proram Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers to make this as well in case you wanted to know what program I was using. I'm also using API 18 to work on this as well.

If you want to take a look at the other files, then let me know.

Comment: Is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: I think the messages are pretty self-explanatory, i.e. `Line 77: missingMessage cannot be resolved or is not a field` for `builder.setMessage(R.string.missingMessage);` pretty much says it all.

Comment: This question is too broad. You can't just dump your whole code and a laundry list of errors. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, it is encouraged that you use Android Studio for app development. It is not clear why you are using the Eclipse Web development version

Comment: Regarding the `deleteSearch(final string tag)` error... `string` is not a variable type. Java is case-sensitive

Comment: I've put this in the **javascript** category since I assumed '.java' files were related to that. Anyways, I made an edit to my question as I got most of the errors fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that some of them are strings that I need to make for the strings.xml file, but would their values have to be messages like "This file is missing", or would they have to be special integers?

They need to be in `res/values/strings.xml`, yes.

Those values are compiled into "special integers" for you and are accessible by `R.string.xxxxx`.

I imagine that solves the majority of the errors saying *"cannot be resolved or is not a field"*.

> DialogInterference cannot be resolved to a type

Did you mean [`DialogInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.html)?

> The method deleteSearch(string) from the type MainActivity refers to the missing type string

Look at this line. What is `string`?

```
private void deleteSearch(final string tag)
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. I added the missing strings and got rid of the other errors you pointed out as they were simple typos. However, the errors at lines 79, 146, 177 and 186 still remain. What could be wrong with those lines? Something isn't right with those lines as they are related to the info on this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html

I'm also using API 18, so could that be the problem as I should use a higher API?

Answer (score 0):

So upon examination, I found out that the other lines did need strings after all despite what it said about certain `R.string` codes on [this page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html) for 'cancel' and 'OK'. So why did 'cancel' and 'OK' need their own strings in strings.xml?